# How to hide the code from showing before search?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hi I am just trying to make the code from displaying before the search button is clicked. The reason I want to hide is that it is showing multiple data and there are multiple data in the database.

So I want to show the search form first and when I click search, the result will show below with the form above. How can I hide the code temporarily before the search. I am really lost and I am not very good with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery to show/hide elements of the page. Also, you can set the css of the element to display:none on the initial load of the page to hide the results.  Then when you are ready to display the results of the search you just use the .show() from jquery.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#results').hide();
            });     
  </script>    
</head>        
<body>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```